# BST insert in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, null

I'm learning C++ and writing a binary search tree. The following is the code I wrote for my insert method.

```
BSTNode * BST::Insert(const std::string & v) {
    BSTNode *n = !root ? root = new BSTNode(v) : Insert_Helper(v,root);
    if(n) size++;
    return n;
}

BSTNode * BST::Insert_Helper(const std::string & v, BSTNode *n) {
    if(!n->value.compare(v))
        return NULL; // already have v
    else if(n->value.compare(v) > 0) // v goes to the left
        if(n->left) return Insert_Helper(v,n->left);
        else return n->left = new BSTNode(v);
    else // v goes to the right
        if(n->right) Insert_Helper(v,n->right);
        else return n->right = new BSTNode(v);
}
```

The bug I'm getting goes like this: It all works fine and dandy, until I try to insert a duplicate node. It doesn't add a new node, yet it increments count.

By observing in GDB, I've found that when I try to add a string that I already have, `Insert_Helper` works correctly and returns NULL. This value however (on my machine) is something like 0x6, which is out of bounds of course, but not 0x0 like I thought it would be. I think this causes an issue at the point where I have the if(n) statement. In this case n evaluates to true, and so increments size one more than it should.

Furthermore, at this point in my program, the nodes continue to get added correctly, but my insert function continues to return 0x6 as the address, even though they really are in valid locations in memory that I can access.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, You would have an easier time with it if you had a single exit and more whitespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your compiler probably should have spotted this, but this line near the end of your helper:

`if(n->right) Insert_Helper(v,n->right);`

You probably should return whatever `Insert_Helper` returns:

`if(n->right) return Insert_Helper(v,n->right);`

Comment: Classic. Wow. An hour of my life gone. But, could have been worse - thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `if(n) size++` to `if (n != NULL) size++`

Comment: It looks like it evaluates to the same thing. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: From the original post "Insert_Helper ... returns NULL, this value however (on my machine) is something like 0x6, which is out of bounds, of course, but not 0x0 like I thought it would be."  It looks like NULL was actually defined as 0 and Insert_Helper didn't return correctly on one code path.  But had NULL been something other than 0, then if(n) would mean something other than if(n != NULL).